# Powershell FTP Connection

Tags: powershell, ftp

I'm using [powershell FTP Client Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-FTP-Client-db6fe0cb) to set a FTP Connection in order to retrieve some files.

I know that I can capture the output of a command in this way:

```
$output = (command) | Out-String
```

I would like to redirect the output of `-Verbose` attribute into a variable.. I'm doing something like this, but the FTP connection can't be created, my scrips just stops.

```
$output1 = (Set-FTPConnection -Server $ftp_server -Credentials $mycreds -Session $session)
$output2 = (
    Get-FTPChildItem -Path $ftp_path -Session $session -Verbose | % {
        $ftpFile = "ftpPathIn/$($_.Name)"
        Get-FTPItem -Path $ftpFile -LocalPath $PathToFile  -Overwrite -Session $session -Verbose
    } ) | Out-String
```

PS: without trying to redirect the output in the variable, the script runs very well. So I Suspect the error is in the way I try to redirect the output in `$output`.
How can I Redirect the output in the variable $output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$output2 = $(
    Get-FTPChildItem -Path $ftp_path -Session $session -Verbose | % {
        $ftpFile = "ftpPathIn/$($_.Name)"
        Get-FTPItem -Path $ftpFile -LocalPath $PathToFile  -Overwrite -Session $session -Verbose
    } ) 4>&1
```

See `Get-Help about_Redirection` for an explanation of the stream redirection syntax.

Comment: For more: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/